# How to implement multi-user app in Java/Android?

Tags: java, android, multi-user

I wanted to write android applications in Java. Applications should work like this : people will be register and login in app. After login user can choose user with they want to co-operate, after that server will give this users the same set of data and each of users can chose some data and sent to server. After that server should chose part of the common data that users chosen before and sent this part again to every user.
I don't know how to implement this. I was thinking about socket or websocket but, i have not idea how it should be look.
Could you give me some advice ?

Answer (score 1):

you would need an server. Parse Server or Firebase would meet your requirement, i prefer parse as its open source. You can rent it from amazon web services or host it free at back4app or host on your own. You can send queries , receive and set how your server collects it and works with it your you can do it manually.